# The number of samples to take vs the chance of good performance

Tags: probability

There are a large number (~$2^{1000}$) of machines with varying performances measured by a real number between $0$ and $1$ (the larger, the better), and we don't know its distribution over performance. I want to know the relationship between $x$, $y$ and $n$ in each of the following two problems, where $n$ has to be small enough ($<50$) and $x,y\in[0,1]$.

1. I sample $n$ data points of them randomly. The machine with the highest performance in them is in the top $x$ in terms of the performance with $y$ of confidence, where top $x$ means top $100x$ percent.
2. I sample $n$ data points of them randomly. The performance of the machine with the highest performance in them is in $[x,1]$ with $y$ of confidence.

Obviously, we can't assume the distribution to be Normal or any known one. How to approach?

Edit: For (1), the answer is $y=1-(1-x)^n$. Solving (2) is not possible without knowing the distribution. Solved! Thanks for advice.

Comment: (1) doesn't need a distribution, as it only cares about the ordering of the machines (it's not that difficult either: It is the inverse of the probability that you have chosen no machines among the top $x$). For number (2), it would be difficult without a concrete distribution assumed, as different distributions give different answers. Perhaps we can assume a distribution on which distribution it truly is?

Comment: I guess solving (1) only is sufficient. Thanks for your remark! Now I think I can do it by myself.